# Issue wiring together spring-data-neo4j standalone spring project

Tags: spring, neo4j, autowired, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to create a sandbox using spring to handle dependency injection. My sandbox is several domain classes, as well as a `MainClass`, which has a `main(String[] args)` method in it.

In annotating my `TestClass` with `@Component` and it just contains

```
@Autowired
private Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate;
```

in it.

In my `main` method, I call `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` on my `applicationContext.xml` file, which is made up of:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.neuralsandbox"/>

<neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/sandbox.db"/>
```

but my program fails to execute at the line here I declare my `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, with a massive stack trace, I'll print the first and last throwables.

First:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.neuralsandbox.TestClass.neo4jTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public final org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a3874640.neo4jTemplate() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingInfrastructure' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public final org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.MappingInfrastructure org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a3874640.mappingInfrastructure() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jTransactionManager' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public final org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a3874640.neo4jTransactionManager()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.<init>(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1073)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.neuralsandbox.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:8)
```

Last:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.<init>(Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService;)V
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.createJtaTransactionManager(Neo4jConfiguration.java:240)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jTransactionManager(Neo4jConfiguration.java:232)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a3874640.CGLIB$neo4jTransactionManager$21(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a3874640$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ed4fda1e.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a3874640.neo4jTransactionManager(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:145)
    ... 72 more
```

I'm using neo4j 1.7 and spring-data-neo4j 2.0.0.RELEASE, as well as spring 3.1.0.RELEASE.

I haven't found a good reason, using the tutorials provided at spring-data-neo4j, for why it would be throwing this exception. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that this is an issue with the mix of spring-data-neo4j and neo4j that I was using.

In spring-data-neo4j 2.0.1.RELEASE, `Neo4jConfiguration` is trying to use `SpringTransactionManager` and `UserTransactionImpl` that take in an `AbstractGraphDatabase` class, and in neo4j 1.7 `SpringTransactionManager` does not take it, and in neo4j 1.8.M01, `UserTransactionImpl` doesn't take it.

So the resolution for now is to use neo4j 1.6.2 and spring-data-neo4j 2.0.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Do you have any news, could you upgrade by now?

Comment: I have not checked in a while, but it looks like spring-data-neo4j is still at a 2.0.1 release, so I do not believe this issue is resolved.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, but I'm using spring-data-neo4j 2.2.0.Release which Maven brings in neo4j 1.8.1.  I don't have to declare that separately. Are you using Maven to draw in the dependencies?  Any luck with the most recent release?

Comment: No, I haven't played around with the latest version. Check your transitive dependencies to make sure spring is the same everywhere.